# Nginx returning 403 forbidden

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5.7

I put a laravel application on a production environment, but the root route (/) is returning 403 Forbiddem, all the other routes work fine! I just can't figure out what I am missing out.

It also works fine on development/local machine.

Here is my routes file:

```
...
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/login');
});

Auth::routes();


Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
    ...
});
...
```

Comment: Can you share your route?

Comment: I edited my post to include the requested file @MHewison

Comment: And when you visit /login do you get a 403?

Comment: Other routes are working fine.